# jquery-ui dropdown menu style

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-ui-menu

i am using jquery-ui 1.9.2 version which has a new menu option in there.
Is there any way that i can change the menu style to be a drop-down just like
    http://onehackoranother.com/projects/jquery/droppy/#

I referred to    http://wiki.jqueryui.com/w/page/12137997/Menu ,but those are plug-ins.

I do not want to use another plugin for this, i want to alter the same jquery-ui itself, is there any way to do this?

Comment: well, i just came to know that we have a menu bar property but it has been removed from the jquery-ui 1.9 versions, u can download it by searching it in google as jquery menubar plugin :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [`position`](http://api.jqueryui.com/menu/#option-position) option to accomplish this. I'll whip up and add a fiddle with the details when I'm less busy, but the gist is:

```
$('#menu').menu({
    position: { my: 'left top', at: 'left bottom' }
});
```

Essentially that is telling jQuery UI to put the sub menu's top-left corner (`my: 'left top'`) on the bottom-left corner of the parent element (`at: 'left bottom'`).

You'll probably need to fiddle with the `jquery.ui.menu.css` file to get it exactly right. I actually ignore that CSS altogether most of the time.